# Powershell Append CSV

Tags: powershell

I am trying to append a CSV file.  Here are the lines I am using.  I wasn't able to find an append option for export-csv unfortunately.  Any ideas would be helpful to get this to work.

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins" | select name, samaccountname | Export-Csv c:\bin\DomainAdmins.csv

$admins = Import-Csv C:\bin\DomainAdmins.csv

foreach ($i in $admins) {Get-ADUser $i.samaccountname -properties * | select name, lastlogondate | Export-Csv c:\bin\dalogon.csv}
```

Comment: You are writing to two different csv files. Where is the append coming into picture? Can you be more clear.

Comment: What exactly do you want to append here? Columns to the original records? Why don't you get them in the first line? If you just want to append another set of items, then use `ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation`, strip the headers and append it to the file with `Add-Content` or `Out-File`. Or add them to the array you imported from the file and write the file anew.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) suggests that there is an `-append` flag.  The example given ends with

```
|  export-csv –append –path \\Archive01\Scripts\Scripts.csv
```

Have you tried that?  It works fine for me.  I'm on version 3, if that matters.

Comment: Doh! Last time I checked I recall it wasn't supported.  Thanks for reminding me to look at documentation.

Comment: No problem, I'm sure tomorrow I'll be in your seat.  I notice you're new to StackOverflow - if this solves you problem, can you check the check mark over by the voting arrows to mark the answer as accepted?  There's also a FAQ around somewhere that describes the whole voting process well, but it looks like someone's gone and redesigned the help section (http://stackoverflow.com/help) while I wasn't looking.

Answer (score 7):

`-Append` was introduced with PowerShell v3, it's not available in PowerShell v2 and earlier. You can work around it like this, though:

```
... |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Out-File -Append "c:\bin\dalogon.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue also a few days ago.  There are a really two solutions I know in Powershell 2.  The first would be to save all the data in an array and then use the export-csv commandlet.  That did not work for me unless I rewrote my script.  I needed to create a CSV and append line by line to build the file.  So, I solved it with out-file -append and changing the encoding to ascii.

I basically created a string with my data in it and then piped it to out-file.  Here is an example:

```
$myCSV = "C:\_PSScripts\data\myCSV.csv"
$firstOutputLine = "Column-1,Column-3,Column-3"
$firstOutputLine | out-file $myCSV -Encoding ascii -Force -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good! but it's only 1 column in CSV file! how to put to many columns as the code below:

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\Program Files\Quest Software\Management Shell for AD\Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.dll'
$group="HO-Internet","Internet1","Internet2","Internet3"
$group |ForEach-Object {Echo "--------------------Group Name $_ ----------------"; Get-QADGroupMember $_ | Select-Object Email,LogonName,ParentContainer,LastLogon,AccountIsDisabled |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation `
    | select -Skip 1 `
    | Out-File -Append "D:\test.csv"}
```

Comment: hmm ... question or answer? If the former, please post a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)